# find all $f$ satisfying $f * f = 1$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Find all $f$ satisfying $$f*f = 1,$$ that is $$\sum_{d|n} f(d)f(\frac{n}{d}) = 1$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

Sol. Clearly, $f(1) = 1$ or $f(1) = -1$
Assume first $f(1) = 1$. Let $p$ be prime. Then $$1 = 2f(p).$$ Now, for any $p, q$ distinct prime, $$1 = 2f(pq) + 2f(p)f(q)$$ which yields $f(pq) = 1/4.$
I guess that $f(p_1p_2...p_k) = 1/2^k$, but proving  by induction involves a complicated terms. Moreover, for general $n$, I am not sure for possible formula.

Any help, or suggestion for a more effective ways to deal with this question ?

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{d | n} f(d) f(n/d) = 1$$

$$ \implies (\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) n^{-s})^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} \sum_{d | n} f(d) f(n/d) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$$
and the trick is 
$$ \implies (\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(p^k)p^{-sk})^2 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty p^{-sk} = \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$$
even when $f(n)$ is not multiplicative.

So we get (using the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series))
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(p^k)p^{-sk} = \pm (1-p^{-s})^{-1/2} = \pm \sum_{k=0}^\infty {-1/2 \choose k} (-1)^k p^{-sk}$$

So that $f(p^k) = \pm {-1/2 \choose k} (-1)^k$.

But we have the right to choose $\pm$ only once : for  $f(1) = \pm 1$ ! Then we have $f(p^k) = f(1) {-1/2 \choose k} (-1)^k$ at every prime power.

Finally, if $f(d)$ is known for every $d | n, d < n$, then

$$\sum_{d | n} f(d)f(n/d) =1 \quad  \implies \quad f(n) = \frac{1}{2f(1)}(1-\sum_{d | n, 1 < d < n} f(d)f(n/d))$$

So once the prime powers are chosen, we have no other choices.

Hence there is the multiplicative solution $f(p^k) = {-1/2 \choose k} (-1)^k, f(n) = \prod_{p^k \| n} f(p^k) $,

and the non-multiplicative solution $f_0(n) = -f(n)$.

$\qquad \scriptstyle \text{note : only formal series are involved here, no convergence problem}$

Comment: I mostly don't understand the argument above. The formula you use in the beginning looks not familair too me. Also, couples of notations like $${\frac{-1}{2}}\choose{k}$$ does not make sense to me. Is it similar to normal binomail coefficient ? (which should be defined for only positive integers)

Comment: @user117375 yes, that's why I added the keyword 'binomial series'. and I use only formal series (no convergence problem)

Comment: @user117375 When $k$ is a non-negative integer then $\binom{n}{k}$ can be written as a polynomial of degree $k$ in the variable $n$.  The resulting polynomial can be evaluated at an arbitrary number such as $n = -\frac12$, which allows us to define $\binom{-1/2}{k}$ without worrying about fractional factorials (which also work but are not as simple).